# Swift: Get a list of opened app windows with desktop number and position info

Tags: swift, macos, applescript, desktop-application

I'm developing a macOS app that would work with app windows.
The goal which I couldn't now afford is to retrieve a list of all opened app windows, which would look something like that (JSON example):

```json
[
  {
    "appName": "Google Chrome",
    "appWindows": [
      {
        "size": {"x": 100, "y": 100}, 
        "position": {"height": 100, "width": 100}, 
        "desktopNumber": 2
      },
      {
        "size": {"x": 100, "y": 100}, 
        "position": {"height": 100, "width": 100}, 
        "desktopNumber": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "appName": "Telegram",
    "appWindows": [
      {
        // full screen app, so has a separate desktop number
        "size": {"x": 1080, "y": 1920}, 
        "position": {"height": 0, "width": 0}, 
        "desktopNumber": 4
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Each app has an array of opened windows alongside a desktop number where it's been opened. A full-size app took a separate desktop space, so it should have a separate desktop number.

I know how to get an opened window list with `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`, but I couldn't find a way to find a desktop number or determine which window is visible or not.

If it's not possible to do with Swift, then perhaps there are apple script solutions?

Answer (score 10):

You can retrieve app names, bounds & displays using following code:

```
import Cocoa
import CoreGraphics

let windowsInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(CGWindowListOption.optionAll, CGWindowID(0))
let maxDisplays: UInt32 = 10
var displays = [CGDirectDisplayID](repeating: 0, count: Int(maxDisplays))
var displayCount: UInt32 = 0
let error = CGGetOnlineDisplayList(maxDisplays, &displays, &displayCount)

for windowInfo in Array<NSDictionary>.fromCFArray(records: windowsInfo) ?? [] {
    if let appName = windowInfo["kCGWindowOwnerName"] as? String {
        print("appName: \(appName)")
    }
    if let bounds = windowInfo["kCGWindowBounds"] as? NSDictionary {
        print ("X: \(bounds["X"] ?? "<unknown>")")
        print ("Y: \(bounds["Y"] ?? "<unknown>")")
        print ("Width: \(bounds["Width"] ?? "<unknown>")")
        print ("Height: \(bounds["Height"] ?? "<unknown>")")

        if
            let x = bounds["X"] as? Double,
            let y = bounds["Y"] as? Double,
            let width = bounds["Width"] as? Double,
            let height = bounds["Height"] as? Double
        {
            for index in 0..<Int(maxDisplays) {
                let display = displays[index]
                let displayRect = CGDisplayBounds(display)
                if displayRect.contains(CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)) {
                    print("Display: \(index)")
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        print("---")
    }
}

extension Array {
    static func fromCFArray(records: CFArray?) -> Array<Element>? {
        var result: [Element]?
        if let records = records {
            for i in 0..<CFArrayGetCount(records) {
                let unmanagedObject: UnsafeRawPointer = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(records, i)
                let rec: Element = unsafeBitCast(unmanagedObject, to: Element.self)
                if (result == nil){
                    result = [Element]()
                }
                result!.append(rec)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
appName: Xcode.app
X: 1284
Y: -1074
Width: 1029
Height: 557
Display: 1
---
appName: Xcode.app
X: 1284
Y: -954
Width: 1029
Height: 261
Display: 1
---
appName: Control Centre
X: 0
Y: 900
Width: 32
Height: 24
---
appName: Control Centre
X: 1294
Y: 0
Width: 146
Height: 24
Display: 0
---
appName: Notes
X: 0
Y: 0
Width: 3200
Height: 24
---
appName: Notes
X: 0
Y: 0
Width: 3200
Height: 24
---
appName: Notes
X: 0
Y: 0
Width: 3200
Height: 24
---
appName: Notes
X: -887
Y: -1333
Width: 3200
Height: 24
Display: 1
---
appName: Notes
X: 0
Y: 0
Width: 1440
Height: 24
Display: 0
---
appName: Notes
X: 0
Y: 0
Width: 1440
Height: 24
Display: 0
---
appName: Notes
X: 0
Y: 0
Width: 1440
Height: 24
Display: 0
---
appName: Notes
X: 0
Y: 0
Width: 1440
Height: 24
Display: 0
---
appName: Notes
X: 0
Y: 0
Width: 1440
Height: 24
Display: 0
---
...
```

Creating the `JSON` object with this code is trivial. Btw, you may want to change:

```
"size": {"x": 1080, "y": 1920}, 
"position": {"height": 0, "width": 0},
```

to

```
"position": {"x": 1080, "y": 1920}, 
"size": {"height": 0, "width": 0},
```

Also, note that apps without a UI may not have a `Display` value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've run your code snippet, but it seems to not work properly.
E.g. I have one `Google Chrome` window, that opened full screen on desktop number 0. But I get as many as 15 `Google Chrome` records returned.
Also, despite I have 4 opened desktops on 2 monitors, all of the records are either with `Display: 0` or without any display value.

Answer (score -1):

**Apple already has Documented this might help you get the most of the info you need**
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1532097-frontmostapplication

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable.